# Volume form on the torus

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, orientation

Let $T = \mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$. I'm trying to find a volume form for the torus, that is, a nowhere-vanishing 2-form. I tried following the idea on this post: [$M \times N$ orientable iff both $M$ and $N$ are orientable proof in terms of volume forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530652/m-times-n-orientable-iff-both-m-and-n-are-orientable-proof-in-terms-of-vo?noredirect=1&lq=1), that is, taking a volume form $\omega$ in $\mathbb{S}^1$ and defining $\omega_T = \pi_1^*\omega\wedge\pi_2^*\omega$, where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the first and second projections, respectively. I'm just having a hard time proving that this is indeed nowhere-vanishing. I tried using $T_{(p,q)}\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1\sim T_p\mathbb{S}^1\times T_q\mathbb{S}^1$, but I'm just getting confused with the tangent vectors. Any help would be appreciated.
Trying to write thing explicitely, it gets even more confusing I find: that is, consider $\omega = ydx-xdy$ as a volume form in $\mathbb{S}^1$. If I see $T_p\mathbb{S}^1$ as a subspace of $T_p\mathbb{R}^2$, then I could see the tangent space of $T$ as a subspace of $T_p\mathbb{R}^4$, that is as the span of $y\partial x-x\partial y$ and $z\partial w -w\partial z$. But then what is $\pi_1^*\omega\wedge\pi_2^*\omega(y\partial x-x\partial y,z\partial w -w\partial z)$? Is it simply $\omega(y\partial x-x\partial y)\omega(z\partial w -w\partial z)=0$? I'm sorry for the ignorance. Also, how could I write $\omega_T$ in terms of $dx,dy,dw$ and $dz$?

Edit: If I consider $\pi_1(x,y,z,w) = (x,y)$, $\pi_2(x,y,z,w) = (z,w)$, then $\pi_1^*\omega = ydx-xdy$ and $\pi_2^*\omega=wdz-zdw$.
Then $$\pi_1^*\omega\wedge\pi_2^*\omega = ywdx\wedge dz-yzdx\wedge dw-xwdy\wedge dz+xz dy\wedge dw$$ so that $\pi_1^*\omega\wedge\pi_2^*\omega(y\partial x-x\partial y,z\partial w -w\partial z)=(x^2+y^2)(z^2+w^2)=1\neq0$.
Is this correct?

Comment: How are you getting confused? Consider $(v,w)\in T_pS^1\times T_qS^1$. Then $\omega_T(v,w) = \omega(v)\omega(w)$. How can this vanish? (It might be less confusing to have different manifolds with different volume forms, but ...)

Comment: @TedShifrin TI think I'm mistaking the definition of nowhere-vanishing: does simply require that there exists $(v,w)\in T_p\mathbb{S}^1\times T_q\mathbb{S}^1$ such that $\omega_T(v,w)\neq 0$? In this case this would make sense. But shouldn't it be $\omega_T(v,w) =\omega(v)\omega(w)-\omega(w)\omega(v)$? Since you must take the tensor product.

Comment: As i said, it’s more confusing having the same manifold in both slots. What is $\pi_1^*\omega(0,w)$? A $k$-form $\phi$ is nowhere-vanishing if for all points $p$, $\phi(p)$ is not the $0$-form on the tangent space at $p$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Shouldn't $\pi_1^*\omega(0,w) = \omega(0) = 0$? I don't see how this implies the formula you gave though... In the post I reference, they mention that simply multiplying the forms wouldn't result in a differential form since it would fail to be antisymmetric.

Comment: Write out $\pi_1^*\omega\otimes\pi_2^*\omega - \pi_2*\omega\otimes\pi_1^*\omega$ evaluated on the pair of vectors. The anti-symmetry complaint is misleading. Work out the details.

Comment: Re your edit: Write out $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ explicitly and compute the pullbacks.

Comment: @TedShifrin Did that, is it ok? I just don't know why I can't figure it out in the general case, I think I don't understand how to compute the wedge product in general.

Comment: You don’t have to expand, but that’s fine. Why don’t you follow my previous suggestions? Use your correct observation three comments earlier.

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried, but I keep getting zero

Comment: It can’t be. Only the “missing” term is $0$. I gave you the answer in the first comment.